# How can I export an object from main.js to utils.js without executing the entire main.js (client side)

Tags: javascript, import

As the title says, I am trying to export an object from main.js to utils.js without executing the entire main.js (client side).
For reference, my main.js looks like this

```js
function init(){
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML += "hey";

    const btn = document.getElementById('change-btn');
    btn.onclick = function () {
        location.href = "utils.html";
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    init();
}

export default class User{
    constructor(height, width){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
}

export const userA = new User(10,5);
```

and my utils.js looks like this

```js
import user from "./main.js";

console.log(user);
```

I want utils to ultimately print the user with 10 as height and 5 as width but I have been stuck on this for a few days :((